# I want to sort one by one left table same right table

Tags: php

I want to sort one by one this below table1 same table2. example:first a class then b class third c class. how can i do with php+mysql. can you answer me?

repeat first a class then b class third c class.

table1

```
 class name   num classid
     9a   name1   5     1
     9a   name4   7     1
     9b   name2   10    2
     9b   name5   6     2
     9c   name3   3     3
     9c   name6   4     3
```

table2

```
   class name   num    classid
     9a   name1   5     1 
     9b   name2  10     2
     9c   name3   3     3
     9a   name4   7     1
     9b   name5   6     2
     9c   name6   4     3
```

[image]

Comment: *"I want to"* is not a proper way to ask a question. Show us what you've tried and what causes you issues

Answer (score 0):

If the class  start alwasy with a number  then you could try removing the number  eg:

```
select  class, name, num  
from my_table  
order by  replace(  class, cast( class +0 AS char) , '')
```